# Security considerations in a nginx and uwsgi serve and django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, django-deployment

I am deploing a django app in a server with ubuntu as SO and nginx with uwsgi for the webserver and I want to know the security configuration I should use.

I deploy the web page in local with virtualbox and everything works fine. The problem is that I want to deploy it and all the tutorial I followed didnt included security. The only thing I know is to secure the webpage with ssl. I am new to this tool and I tried to read the security documentacion of nginx and uwsgi and I dont understand anything